# How to retrieve all the constraints on a table along with referenced column and table name as well

Tags: oracle, join, constraints

I am able to list all the constraints using the below query except that I don't get foreign key column and table in it -

```
Select a.OWNER, a.CONSTRAINT_NAME, a.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,c.COLUMN_NAME, a.TABLE_NAME, a.SEARCH_CONDITION from ALL_CONSTRAINTS a JOIN all_cons_columns c 
ON a.CONSTRAINT_NAME=c.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
AND a.OWNER = 'OWNER' AND a.TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME';
```

Now, I am able to list the foreign key using below query but then it just gives me only the foreign/referenced key and table details.

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
  AND a.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Is there a way I can get all the constraints along with referenced key and table name may be using the above two queries or otherwise? I have tried a lot but not able to figure that out.

Like From first query above I get -

[image]

And from second query, I get only Foreign key constraint related details -
[image]

I need a way to get a combination of these two and get columns -

```
OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_CONDITION, R_OWNER, R_TABLE_NAME, R_PK
```

Hope that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select fk.table_name
     , fk.constraint_name as fk
     , listagg(fkc.column_name, ', ') within group (order by fkc.position) as fk_columns
     , pk.table_name as parent_table
from   user_constraints fk
       join user_cons_columns fkc
            on  fkc.table_name = fk.table_name
            and fkc.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
       join user_constraints pk
            on  pk.constraint_name = fk.r_constraint_name
            and pk.owner = fk.r_owner
where  fk.constraint_type = 'R'
and    pk.constraint_type in ('U','P')
group by
       fk.table_name
     , fk.constraint_name
     , pk.table_name
     , pk.constraint_name
order by fk.table_name, pk.table_name;
```

This uses the `user_` views (objects you own). To extend this to other schemas, use the `all_` (objects you have access to) or `dba_` (everything) views, e.g:

```
select fk.owner
     , fk.table_name
     , fk.constraint_name as fk
     , listagg(fkc.column_name, ', ') within group (order by fkc.position) as fk_columns
     , pk.table_name as parent_table
from   all_constraints fk
       join all_cons_columns fkc
            on  fkc.owner = fk.owner
            and fkc.table_name = fk.table_name
            and fkc.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
       join all_constraints pk
            on  pk.constraint_name = fk.r_constraint_name
            and pk.owner = fk.r_owner
where  fk.constraint_type = 'R'
and    pk.constraint_type in ('U','P')
group by
       fk.owner
     , fk.table_name
     , fk.constraint_name
     , pk.table_name
     , pk.constraint_name
order by fk.owner, fk.table_name, pk.table_name;
```

Filter for a specific table or table name pattern in the `where` clause.

Replace `all_` with `dba_` if you are not seeing the tables you want and you have access to the `dba_` views.

Edit: if you want to include PKs and FKs in the same report, you can use the following. It doesn't show check constraints because the check condition is in an inaccessible `LONG` column and most of them will be `NOT NULL` constraints with system-generated names which clutter up the report and aren't generally helpful.

```
select co.owner
     , co.table_name
     , case co.constraint_type
           when 'P' then 'Primary key'
           when 'U' then 'Unique'
           when 'R' then 'Foreign key'
       end as constraint_type
     , co.constraint_name
     , listagg(coc.column_name, ', ') within group (order by coc.position) as columns
     , pk.table_name as fk_parent
from   all_tables t
       join all_constraints co
            on  co.owner = t.owner
            and co.table_name = t.table_name
       join all_cons_columns coc
            on  coc.owner = co.owner
            and coc.table_name = co.table_name
            and coc.constraint_name = co.constraint_name
       left join all_constraints pk
            on  pk.constraint_name = co.r_constraint_name
            and pk.owner = co.r_owner
            and pk.constraint_type in ('U','P')
where  co.constraint_type in ('U','P','R')
and    t.owner = user
group by
       co.owner
     , co.table_name
     , co.constraint_name
     , co.constraint_type
     , pk.table_name
     , pk.constraint_name
order by co.owner, co.table_name
     , case co.constraint_type when 'P' then 1 when 'U' then 2 else 3 end
     , pk.table_name;
```

Comment: It doesn't return me anything but just four column names like TABLE_NAME, FK, FK_COLUMNS, PARENT_TABLE. Do I need to update anything here?

Comment: I did the following changes : replaced `user_cons_columns` with `all_cons_columns` and `user_constraints` with `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`. Now I see some results, but no primary or check constraints. Just foreign key.

Comment: Maybe if you describe what report you want someone can write it for you.

Comment: William, I have updated my question. Hope that gives an insight above my requirement. Truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for. I know it's not optimized, any edits/suggestions for the same are warmly appreciated.

```
SELECT   ac.table_name,
         column_name,
         --position,
         ac.constraint_name,
         ac.constraint_type,
         --DECODE (constraint_type, 'P', 'Primary Key', 'Foreign Key') key_type,
         (SELECT ac2.table_name
            FROM all_cons_columns ac2
           WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            fK_to_table,
         (SELECT ac2.column_name
            FROM all_cons_columns ac2
           WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            fK_to_column
    FROM all_cons_columns acc, all_constraints ac
   WHERE     acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name
         AND acc.table_name = ac.table_name
         AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R', 'C', 'U')
         AND ac.TABLE_NAME='<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>'
         --AND ac.table_name = 'ACCOUNT' (your table here)
ORDER BY table_name, constraint_type, position;
```

Slightly better version could be-

```
SELECT ac.owner, ac.table_name, LISTAGG(acc.column_name ,',' ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ac.constraint_name) AS "column_list" , ac.constraint_name, ac.constraint_type, ac.search_condition_vc,
        ac2.table_name as fK_to_table, ac2.column_name as fK_to_column
        FROM  all_constraints ac
        JOIN all_cons_columns  acc ON acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R', 'C', 'U')
        LEFT OUTER JOIN all_cons_columns ac2 ON ac2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME         
        group by ac.owner, ac.table_name, ac.constraint_name, 
        ac.constraint_type, ac.search_condition_vc, ac2.table_name, ac2.column_name;
```